# Magic number for new file system

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel

I am writing new stackable file system, all the file systems have associated magic number which acts like their "signature" for file formats. I was wondering how to decide this number for my file system? is there a way to ensure that the number I choose is not already taken? And once taken, do I need to register that number somewhere marking it as used? These numbers are to be defined at `/include/api/linux/magic.h`

Answer (score 1):

When ever a new file system is added, it's responsibility of developer to assign it unique magic number. Set some number for e.g., 0xAAFF8023 etc and check in magic.h for uniqueness. This way, once attached, future developers will ensure that they don't take what you've assigned. Note that ext2/3/4 are designed to be on-disk format compatible, hence they have same magic number. There is no harm in having same magic number if developer assigns it carefully, knowing the impact.